# Undefined reference to t1sl_steup_key_block when linking OpenSSL

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, linker-errors

I got a problem of linking an OpenSSL library into an existing project.
Where I do get it wrong?

Below are the steps I have followed.

I have downloaded the SSL library, configured and installed it. It gets installed in `/usr/local/ssl`.

2)  I have copied `libcrypto.a` and `libssl.a` from `/usr/local/ssl/lib` into my project, something like `/mnt/linux/bla/bla/lib`.

3)  Then I edit the make file and added path of libssl libcrpto there. The path added is one that is in project like `/mnt/linux/bla /bla`

3) make

4) build project via slick edit

When it builds I get a long error chain, like

```
../lib/libssl.a(t1_enc.o) :In function 't1sl_steup_key_block: undefined ref
```

Now, I guess copying .a files into project could be problem. Is there is any alternative for that or should I use `ln -s` to link .a files form `/usr/local/openssl/lib` into my project library folder? Below is the error.

```
   Debug/FC5/m2pa.o  -ldl -lpthread -ltdapi ../septel/gctlib.lib ../lib/libpq.a ../asn1/lib/libasn1per.a ../mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.a     -L../lib ../asn1/lib/libasn1rt.a -lm -lcrypt -lcrypto -lssl  -rdynamic
../lib/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o): In function `SSL_set_quiet_shutdown':ssl_lib.c:(.text+0x670): multiple definition of `SSL_set_quiet_shutdown'
../mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.a(ssl.o):ssl.cpp:(.text+0x125c): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: Warning: size of symbol `SSL_set_quiet_shutdown' changed from 45 in ../mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.a(ssl.o) to 12 in ../lib/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o)
../lib/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o): In function `SSL_get_quiet_shutdown':ssl_lib.c:(.text+0x680): multiple definition of `SSL_get_quiet_shutdown'
../mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.a(ssl.o):ssl.cpp:(.text+0x12down' changed from 35 in ../mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.a(ssl.o) to 8 in ../lib/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o)
../lib/libssl.a(ssl_err2.o): In function `SSL_load_error_strings':ssl_err2.c:(.text+0x4): undefined reference to `ERR_load_crypto_strings'
../lib/libssl.a(ssl_algs.o): In function `SSL_library_init':ssl_algs.c:(.text+0x4): undefined reference to `EVP_des_cbc'
:ssl_algs.c:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `EVP_add_cipher'
:ssl_algs.c:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `EVP_des_ede3_cbc'
:ssl_algs.c:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `EVP_add_cipher'
:ssl_algs.c:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `EVP_idea_cbc'
```

Comment: Need more information. But, I have libssl.a libcrypto.o in my build (I am building cross platform and need target specifc builds) and just link normally. Do you have -lm -ldl in the link line? I would need to see what symbols are missing to be able to guess what you are not linking in.

Comment: @PAntonie .. Thanks for reply . My first doubt is " do  you think its correct procedure to just copy libcrypto.a and libssl.a from /usr/local/ssl/lib  into my project  lib folder?    OR do i need to to do soft link  like ln -s

Comment: this is my line of addition in make file _italic_ **bold** '# Common libraries
COM_LIB=-ldl -lpthread -ltdapi ../septel/gctlib.lib ../lib/libpq.a \
        ../asn1/lib/libasn1per.a \
    ../mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.a     ../lib/libcrypto.a     ../lib/libssl.a\
        ../asn1/lib/libasn1rt.a -lm -lcrypt -lcrypto -lssl 
'

Comment: Ok, your build line you are including libssl and libcrypto twice. Once explicitly (../lib/libssl.a and later -ssl - same for libcrypto) you should do -L ../lib and then -lssl. That might be your problem if you are using gcc. Else, you might try `-Wl, start-group <your library list> -Wl, end-group` around the list of libraries so GCC looks up the symbols correctly. I do need to see your errors, the undefined symbols maybe telling you what libs you are missing.

Comment: PS: You do not need to have libssl.a libcrypto.a in your build tree. Unless you are doing cross-platform stuff then you should have the correct version in your tree (or better get the SSL source and build it for your target).

Comment: I changed the make file and just included -lssl -lcrypto  and _L../lib . The files libcrypto.a and libssl.a are in my lib folder of my project. When I build , it still throws undefined error . DO u think that since header files are in /usr/local/openssl/include , it might causing problem?

Comment: No. You are linking, include files are for compilation. I need to see the undefined symbols error. That will tell you what is wrong. You are missing a binary symbol during the link, or the link order is wrong. Have you tried the `-Wl,start-group` and `-Wl,end-group` ?

Comment: @PAntonie .. I have added few of the error in my posted message.

Comment: First check your version of libcrypto.a is built properly. `nm ../lib

Comment: First check your version of libcrypto.a is built properly. `nm ../lib/libcrypto.a | grep EVP_add` (you should get 4 items - cipher and digest). Also, mysqlclient.a and openssl.a are clashing as you have duplicate symbols. Do you need to use the openssl libraries? Is this already built into libmysqlclient.a?

Comment: PS: try this:  `-Wl,start-group  -ldl -lpthread -ltdapi ../septel/gctlib.lib ../lib/libpq.a ../asn1/lib/libasn1per.a ../mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.a     -L../lib ../asn1/lib/libasn1rt.a -lm -lcrypt -lcrypto -lssl  -rdynamic -Wl,end-group` it fixes library search order problems.

Comment: @PAntonie when i did nm ../lib/libcrypto.a | grep EVP_add. I got 6 items instead of 4

Comment: I tried -Wl option in make file and it failed to recognise start-group.  when i just did -lssl without -L ../lib  it complies fine BUT AT RUNTIME  it throws error something like failed to load libssl.so.6 \;shared object etc

Comment: nm ../lib/libcrypto.a | grep EVP_add
00000330 T EVP_add_cipher   
00000260 T EVP_add_digest  
         U EVP_add_cipher  
         U EVP_add_digest  
         U EVP_add_cipher  
         U EVP_add_digest   I am bit worried about U sign , which i guess mean undefined

Comment: Ok. If you take out the -L you are using the system library. You need to find libssl.so.6 (try `find / -name libssl.so.6`) and then set up `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH += <the path to the file you found>`. This also means you are loading the shared version, which I guess is the one you want. The `T` means it has been found. Looks like you have two different versions of libssl. What compiler are you using and what is the link line?

Comment: sorry it should be: `-Wl,--start-group` and `-Wi,--end-group`.

Comment: @PAnotnie -> I guess the issue has been solved( may be temporary). I did ldd of my exceutable file and found that it could find /lib/libcrypto.so.6 and /lib/libssl.so.6 . while in /lib directory there are version of crypto and ssl but not 6 . so I  created  the softlink like ln-s  libcrypto.so.6 libcrypto.so.0.9.8g  .simalrily  for libssl . And it seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the libssl and libcrypto already installed in your /usr/lib directory (assuming you've installed the dev packages for both)? Once that compiles and runs without error using the default install, you can build your new libssl/libcrypto(?) from source, install to usr/local, and rebuild using the usr/local versions of the libraries.

Comment: I guess the issue has been solved( may be temporary). I did ldd of my exceutable file and found that it could find /lib/libcrypto.so.6 and /lib/libssl.so.6 . while in /lib directory there are version of crypto and ssl but not 6 . so I created the softlink like ln-s libcrypto.so.6 libcrypto.so.0.9.8g .simalrily for libssl . And it seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the flag `-lssl` and `-lcrypto` in your makefile'

For example:

```
gcc somefile.c -o someprogram -lssl -lcrypto
```

Comment: i actually did that . In my make file I added -lssl  and bang it complies without any error . But at runtime it throws me error like failed to load libssl.so.6 . bla bla