# make fails to compile, undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I am trying to install an open source project on my ubuntu 13:04 but the make process fails on  a method in a class called **updateDB.c**. During compilation, i have this error :

```
updateDB.o: In function `update_cache_hash':
/usr/local/src/bgpinspect-0.5/src/updateDB.c:142: undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
/usr/local/src/bgpinspect-0.5/src/updateDB.c:143: undefined reference to `EVP_DigestFinal_ex'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [BGPdb] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/bgpinspect-0.5/src'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This is the method **update_cache_hash** that fails :

```
static uint16_t update_cache_hash( char *buff, int size ) {
    unsigned char md_hash[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
    unsigned int md_len;
    uint16_t hash;

    EVP_DigestUpdate(&global_table.ctx, buff, size );
    EVP_DigestFinal_ex(&global_table.ctx, md_hash, &md_len);

    if ( md_len < 2 ) {
        ps_log( PS_LOG_ERROR, "EVP_DigestFinal_ex returned a short hash.\n" );
        return 0;
    }

    hash = ( (uint16_t) md_hash[md_len - 2] << 8 ) | md_hash[md_len - 1];
    hash = UPDATE_CACHE_MASK( hash );

    return hash;
}
```

The top of this class has an include statement

```
#include <openssl/evp.h>
```

I have openssl installed on my computer alongside libssl-dev ; I can't figure out why it gives that error since i am new with c and static links etc. 
I have **evp.h** on this path : **/usr/include/openssl/evp.h**

So how may i change the makefile or configure to maybe fix this issue ? because it seems make can't see this path **/usr/include/openssl/evp.h**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `undefined reference` error is a linker error, so it appears that `gcc` is finding `/usr/include/openssl/evp.h` but the linker is unable to find the library that has the `EVP_DigestUpdate` and `EVP_DigestFinal_ex` functions.

I'd check that the makefile in question has an `-lcrypto` argument and that `make` is finding the right `libcrypto` on your system.

Comment: one more tip for anybody having this problem, make sure `-lssl` comes before `-lcrypto` :) The order matters, go-fig.

Answer (score 0):

The linker cannot find the libssl functions.  You need to link libssl to your project.

There are suggestions in this SO article: [Undefined reference to t1sl_steup_key_block when linking OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700617/linking-problem-of-openssl-library-in-existing-c-project)

For example, in your makefile, you'd add -lssl:

```
gcc somefile.c -o someprogram -lssl
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) -lssl was already in the make file except -libcrypto which did the trick