# Link error when using AES256 example with OpenSSL

Tags: c, linker, openssl

Using gcc 4.8.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 to compile openssl example.

```
gcc SSLsample.c -lssl3
```

The linker gives undefined symbols:

```
SSLsample.c:(.text+0x25d): undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new'
SSLsample.c:(.text+0x272): undefined reference to `EVP_aes_256_cbc'
SSLsample.c:(.text+0x294): undefined reference to `EVP_DecryptInit_ex'
SSLsample.c:(.text+0x2bc): undefined reference to `EVP_DecryptUpdate'
SSLsample.c:(.text+0x2ed): undefined reference to `EVP_DecryptFinal_ex'
SSLsample.c:(.text+0x309): undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sample] Error 1
```

There are many libraries under engines, but they are listed as alternate implementations, what is the main implementation?

The suggestions to link with -lssl and -lcrypt sounded good, but look:

```
gcc SSLsample.c  -lssl -lcrypt
/tmp/cczNovmQ.o: In function `main':
SSLsample.c:(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `ERR_load_crypto_strings'
SSLsample.c:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_no\
conf'
SSLsample.c:(.text+0x59): undefined reference to `OPENSSL_config'
SSLsample.c:(.text+0xc6): undefined reference to `BIO_dump_fp'
SSLsample.c:(.text+0x12c): undefined reference to `EVP_cleanup'
SSLsample.c:(.text+0x131): undefined reference to `ERR_free_strings'
/tmp/cczNovmQ.o: In function `handleErrors':
SSLsample.c:(.text+0x167): undefined reference to `ERR_print_errors_fp'
/tmp/cczNovmQ.o: In function `encrypt':
SSLsample.c:(.text+0x18c): undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new'
SSLsample.c:(.text+0x1a1): undefined reference to `EVP_aes_256_cbc'
SSLsample.c:(.text+0x1c3): undefined reference to `EVP_EncryptInit_ex'
SSLsample.c:(.text+0x1eb): undefined reference to `EVP_EncryptUpdate'
SSLsample.c:(.text+0x21c): undefined reference to `EVP_EncryptFinal_ex'
SSLsample.c:(.text+0x238): undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free'
/tmp/cczNovmQ.o: In function `decrypt':
SSLsample.c:(.text+0x25d): undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new'
SSLsample.c:(.text+0x272): undefined reference to `EVP_aes_256_cbc'
SSLsample.c:(.text+0x294): undefined reference to `EVP_DecryptInit_ex'
SSLsample.c:(.text+0x2bc): undefined reference to `EVP_DecryptUpdate'
SSLsample.c:(.text+0x2ed): undefined reference to `EVP_DecryptFinal_ex'
SSLsample.c:(.text+0x309): undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linking problem of OpenSSL library in existing C project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700617/linking-problem-of-openssl-library-in-existing-c-project).

Comment: The library name is "libcrypto" (with an "o"), not "libcrypt". Link with `-lcrypto`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ciphers, such as AES256, and other encryption utilities are part of the libcrypto library; libssl is primarily concerned with the SSL/TLS protocol. Link with `-lcrypto` instead of `-lssl3`.

Comment: I don't think `-lssl3` is the name of a library provided by OpenSSL. Is is part of one of the knock-off ports, like Boring or Libre?

Answer (score 5):

> ```
>  gcc SSLsample.c -lssl3
> ```

Use:

```
gcc SSLsample.c -o sample.exe -lssl -lcrypto
```

The names and order of the library matters. its `libssl` and `libcrypto`, and `libcrypto` must follow `libssl` because `libssl` depends upon `libcrypto`.

You could also use static archives:

```
gcc SSLsample.c /usr/lib/libssl.a /usr/lib/libcrypto.a -o sample.exe
```

That avoids problems with linker and library paths, and `LD_PRELOAD` tricks at runtime.

Comment: gcc SSLsample.c /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.a   are in a slightly different place, but linking with them does not help

Comment: @Dov - you need `libcrypto.a`, not `libcrypt.a`. Notice the addition of the letter ***`o`***. I think `crypt` is the thing that gives you Unix passwords for the password file.